# What is the correct method for dynamically setting titles for views in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: dynamic, text, view, sencha-touch-2

I am currently setting view titles in a sencha touch 2 view like so:

```
initialize: function() {
     this.callParent();
     var translator = Ext.create('MyApp.util.Translation');
     this.config.title = translator.translateData('pagetitle.detail');
}
```

The translation class just looks up a string from a javascript object based ont the key provided in the `translator.translateData` function.

With this approach when the view has loaded the title shifts slightly to right (40 px or so).

I have also tried placing this in a view listener `activate` with similar results.

What is the correct method for dynamically setting a view title in ST2?

Comment: Do you work with a navigation view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way via the Controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            titlebar: {
                autoCreate: true,
                selector: '#mytitlebar',
                xtype: 'titlebar'
            }
        },

        control: {
            "titlebar#mytitlebar": {
                initialize: 'onTitlebarInitialize'
            }
        }
    },

    onTitlebarInitialize: function(component, options) {
        var me = this;
        me.getTitlebar().setTitle("Second Title");
       // OR IN YOUR CASE:
       var translator = Ext.create('MyApp.util.Translation');
       me.getTitlebar().setTitle(translator.translateData('pagetitle.detail'));
    }
});
```

Views:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                itemId: 'mytitlebar',
                title: 'First Title'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Comment: I have tried this before. First off, `this.setTitle()` is `undefined` and, even using `item.config.title =` results in the screen title never being set.